# How do I edit '/etc/ld.so.conf' in a yocto recipe?

Tags: linux, embedded, yocto, ld, bitbake

As suggested by [Zac Anger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5774952/zac-anger), i copy [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76320472/how-do-i-edit-etc-ld-so-conf-in-a-yocto-recipe?noredirect=1#comment134584192_76320472) question over here:

I have a yocto recipe in which I copy/install some stuff to an image. After that, I want to add a line to the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file like this, so that the dynamic loader finds my library files:

```
do_install(){
  # install some stuff...

  echo /opt/myStuff/lib >> /etc/ld.so.conf
  ldconfig
}
```

During the build process I get the following error which aborts the build process:

```
...
| DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
| /home/debian/Devel/myYocto/build/tmp/work/myTarget/myRecipe/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_install.3176: 203: cannot create /etc/ld.so.conf: Permission denied
| WARNING: exit code 2 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/debian/Devel/myYocto/poky/meta-myLayer/myRecipe/myRecipe.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '1'
```

Now to my question: How do I add a custom path to the dynamic loader by adding a line or editing the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file in a yocto recipe?

Comment: Since `root` is needed to do as described... Perhaps consider `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable instead? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30672393/3196753

Comment: You are getting the permission error because you are trying to update the file on your build machine. You want to do it for the build image rootfs, so do `echo /opt/myStuff/lib >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/ld.so.conf` instead. And, I don't think you need ldconfig(8) in your recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want that addition in the `/etc/ld.so.conf` of your target system, but

```
echo /opt/myStuff/lib >> /etc/ld.so.conf
```

would change that file on your build host. Fortunally, this gives an error.

Your target rootfs is `$D`, so your file would be unter `$D/etc/ld.so.conf`, but more generally, the file doesn't need to be located in `/etc`, so you would use `${D}${sysconfdir}/ld.so.conf`.

But then you experienced the problem that you can't do that in `do_install()`, because different receipes would generate separate `ld.so.conf`, leading to conflicts. Thus, better work with a `ld.so.conf.d`:

```
install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/ld.so.conf.d/
echo /opt/myStuff/lib >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/ld.so.conf.d/myStuff.conf
```

Or, even better, put that file in your recipe and do

```
install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/myStuff.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}/ld.so.conf.d/
```

Also, don't run `ldconfig` on your host. Some Yocto magic will update your library cache anyhow.